# installation of Oozie on a separate machine then Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Very new to Oozie, hence please excuse me if I sound like a newbie.
I have a hadoop cluster which is up and running. I want to install Oozie, this i want on a separate machine then then hadoop. Is this possible? the reason for asking is that on every installation guide I have seen it asks to install hadoop on the machine hence am not sure if its technically possible to have hadoop on a separate machine then Oozie.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oozie server serves client's requests, it's a web application which uses embedded Tomcat, it can be installed on any machine where hadoop is reachable from, it's not tied to hadoop by itself. You can specify hadoop's `nameNode` and `jobTracker` in workflow properties so oozie will know where to send it's jobs.